# How can I pass a shortcut to a `.pdf` to `\includegraphics{}`?

Tags: graphics, links

I'd like to pass shortcuts to `\includegraphics`.

I have the following project structure

```
/project/report/main.tex
/project/report/myplotshortcut
/project/code/r/output/myplot.pdf
```

And file:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\inlcudegraphics{myplotshortcut}
\end{docuemnt}
```

where `myplotshortcut` is a shortcut to `myplot.pdf`.

Things work fine when I pass `myplot.pdf` directly. The shortcut seems to break things. There's no mention of a "pass shortcut" option in the `graphicx` manual.  HOWEVER, in my post [Project directory organization: where does the output go](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/project-directory-organization-where-does-code-output-go) it was mentioned that I should include dynamic links. My understanding is that (basically) symlinks are to Linux as shortcuts are to Windows.

Q: Does what I've posted above work fine with symlinks (as suggested in that linked post)?

Q: If it does, how can I set up a similar architecture using Windows shortcuts?

UPDATE: I figured out how to make an actual symlink using the `mklink` function from the command line. Still no dice. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to point the `graphicx` package to  `/project/code/r/output/`  by using the `\graphicspath{}` command?

Comment: Windows has [NTFS junctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) which are similar to symlinks.

Comment: @Alan: for modularity's sake, I'm trying to get `main.tex` to only call on files from within its working directory (as suggested in that post I linked). However, what the responder suggested doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *"My understanding is that (basically) symlinks are to Linux as shortcuts are to Windows."* Thats true: Symlinks are as awesome as Linux and shortcuts are as ... as Windows. Note that symlinks are resolved at the file system layer, i.e. much deeper than shortcuts which I think are resolved in the application layer and are basically just special files holding the linked path.

Comment: @Ben, Martin: Windows also has Unix-style symlinks (in addition to junctions and hard links, not as a replacement). Windows shortcuts (`*.lnk` files) are interpreted by the GUI shell and correspond to `*.desktop` files often found on Linux desktop environments (e.g. Gnome or KDE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: Does what I've posted above work fine with symlinks [under Unix/Linux] (as suggested in that linked post)?

A: Yes, as long as the symlink has the proper extension:
So
`myplotshortcut.pdf -> /project/code/r/output/myplot.pdf` works fine, but
`myplotshortcut -> /project/code/r/output/myplot.pdf` doesn't, which is due to the way the `graphics/x` packag(s) work.

---

Q: If it does, how can I set up a similar architecture using Windows shortcuts?

A: With a shortcut it wont work because (La)TeX doesn't support them. You can use [`mklink`](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/mklink) on NTFS file systems (i.e. under Win 7, Vista, 2k, NT etc. but not under older FAT-based Windows versions) 
like you already pointed out, but I will need to add the correct extension also in this case!

Comment: Yes, that did work. I had tested things out, adding a `.pdf` extension in the shortcut case but not the symlink case. That was the trick.