# Using relative paths for \include commands

Tags: include

I have a top-level latex file: `/thesis.tex`

And subfolders with chapters: `/chap1/ch1.tex`

In `thesis.tex` I use `\include` commands like so:

```
\include{chap1/ch1}
```

And in `ch1.tex` I have more includes for the sections of the chapter:

```
\include{introduction}
```

The `ch1.tex` file and all its included sections use relative paths as above (this was a standalone document that is now a chapter of the larger thesis.tex doc). I realize I have to fix all the paths in the include statements for `ch1.tex` and its sections to respect the main document directory as the root:

```
\include{chap1/introduction}
```

Is there another way? Do I have to go through and change all the include and figure references in this way, or is there a way I can tell all such links to use relative paths within ch1?

Comment: [You shouldn't use `include` but `input` within a chapter...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: You have `chap1` in one place, but then mention `ch1` in another. Also, a leading slash denotes an absolete path. Is your `thesis.tex` really in `/`? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the `import` package is what you need.

Comment: Related question [include - How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is best to use relative paths, that way if you move the entire directory tree things will still work. So use

```
\newcommand*{\MyPath}{../thesis}%
\input{\MyPath/chap1/ch1.tex}
```

So assuming that you have your files as:

```
<some path>/thesis/thesis.tex
<some path>/thesis/chap1/ch1.tex
<some path>/thesis/chap2/ch2.tex
```

All the files are input relative to where they are with respect to the *thesis* directory.

I am pretty sure that you'll need to update all of your `\input` statements, but this way it is flexible in case you decide to change the top level directory, or move it somewhere.

Comment: How do I do this in Plain TeX?

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: I don't use Plain TeX but I think using `\def\MyPath{../thesis}` and the Plain TeX equivalent of `\input`. Perhaps you could post a new question if that does not work.

Comment: Is there an easier way that doesn't involve a hack like this?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Not sure how to help you. Perhaps if I knew what part of this you consider a hack, it might be easier to help. I think you should post a new question and detail what you want to accomplish and the problems with the approaches outlined here.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks! I did here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274457/relative-paths-to-tex-files It is suggested to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128067/using-a-non-centralized-structure-for-tex-files-similar-to-graphicspath

Comment: How does it solve anything? It just splits the incorrectly interpreted path into two pieces. As soon as the build is started from a directory that is not `thesis`, all the paths break again, because they are interpreted _relative to the directory in which the build is started_, not relative to the currently processed file.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: It solves it for those cases where there is a particular project which has a specific hierarchial organization. I use this for a very large project with thousands of files and works fine for me. I suspect your case has different requirements and is difficult to help you further without knowing what those requirements are -- I suggest you post a new question detailing your requirements. I am sure you are not the only one who has an issue with this answer, so your question will probbaly be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is pretty old but since this post was the first on tex.sx I found this might be of help.

As proposed by Martin, a solution to the problem could be to use the import package as explained in [How to use the import package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58465/how-to-use-the-import-package).

Answer (score 2):

Adding this as a separate answer as I am **not** recommend using this method as it likely more work than it is worth, and that is to modify the input macro to do a search for a file over a list of directories and include that. This would have the advantage that you would not need to change each of the individual files, and allow you to move files around and still have them work.

If you decide to pursue this approach this question on [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/how-to-iterate-through-the-name-of-files-in-a-folder/24505#24505) might be helpful.