# How to use the import package?

Tags: input, import, subfiles

I've read about the import package and am now trying to use it in my document, but I only run into errors. 
I have a main file named `/ProjectPath/header.tex` which loads all packages, etc. Additionally, some further customisations are located in `/ProjectPath/header/` and are loaded by `/ProjectPath/header.tex`.

Now I have several chapters like `/ProjectPath/chap1/` etc. Usually, I had all my files (the header files, the chapter files, the subchapter files, etc.) in one single folder and could easily compile Chapter1:

```
\input{header}

\begin{document}
    …
\end{document}
```

To get more clarity it is of course useful to put the files into folders. I've read the documentation about the import package but I do not understand how to use the `\import` command.

Lets say I have following configuration:

```
/ProjectPath/header.tex             %% main file
/ProjectPath/header/custom1.tex     %% is loaded by header.tex
/ProjectPath/header/custom2.tex     %% is loaded by header.tex

/ProjectPath/chap1/part1.tex
/ProjectPath/chap1/part2.tex
/ProjectPath/chap1/part3.tex
/ProjectPath/chap1/part4.tex
/ProjectPath/chap1/chapter1.tex     %% whole first chapter, can be compiled separately

/ProjectPath/chap2/part1.tex
/ProjectPath/chap2/part2.tex
/ProjectPath/chap2/part3.tex
/ProjectPath/chap2/part4.tex
/ProjectPath/chap2/chapter2.tex     %% whole second chapter, can be compiled separately

/ProjectPath/Document.tex           %% whole document, includes both chapters
```

Of course, now I can't use `\input{../header.tex}` in `/ProjectPath/chap1/chapter1.tex`. I am sure, I can get this fixed with the import package, but how?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** Sorry for missing MWE. Here it is:

In the simplest case I have the following files:

```
/header.tex
/header/custom.tex   %% is imported by header.tex
/chap1/part1.tex     %% loads header.tex
```

Contents:

```
%% header.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import} 
\subimport{header}{custom}

%% part1.tex
\input{../header}
\begin{document}
    Text.
\end{document}
```

Compiling part1.tex yields in:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `custom.tex' not found.

Latex Error: ../header.tex:4 Emergency stop.
```

What's wrong? I'm a bit slow today, I still don't get the correct use of the import package…

Comment: Try switching the use of `\input` and `\subimport` (cf. my answer).

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example showing the import of a higher-level file by a file in a subfolder, which is what I understood you want to achieve with the header file. A file `chapter1.tex` is located in a `/subfolder`. It loads two files: `part1.tex`, which is located in the same `/subfolder`, and `partA.tex` from the home folder. `partA.tex` also loads `part1.tex`; it therefore corresponds to the header file in the example you've added.

Using `subimport{}{}` is necessary for `partA.tex` to let it use its own path to find `part1.tex`. Since the latter does not make any further imports, it can always be included by means of `input`.

```
main.tex    
partA.tex              %your header.tex
subfolder/chapter1.tex
subfolder/part1.tex    %your custom.tex
```

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \subimport*{subfolder/}{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

```
%subfolder/chapter1.tex
\section{Chapter 1}

\input{part1}
%\input{../partA}   %doesn't work
\subimport*{../}{partA}
```

```
%/subfolder/part1.tex
\subsection{Part 1}
\lipsum[1]
```

```
%partA.tex
\subsection{Part A} 
\lipsum[2]

\input{subfolder/part1}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between `\subimport*{}` and `\subimport{}`? Nothing in the [import package docs](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf).

Comment: @Sav-econ – Yes there is.  "Historically, ‘star’ versions of the commands were defined (to avoid searching the `TEXINPUTS` path) but now the “`∗`” is ignored."  In other words, there is no different nowadays.  But perhaps when this answer was written (back in 2012) there was.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [`import`](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf) package description, the `\subimport` command is your friend. You can use it like this:

```
\subimport{subdirectory}{filename}
```

or, a few examples in your case:

```
\subimport{header}{custom1}
...
\subimport{chap1}{part1}
```

...and so on. Apparently the extension of the file is not required

Comment: My header file includes:

`\usepackage{import}

\subimport{header}{custom1}
\subimport{header}{custom2}`

Now, chapter1 includes:

`\input{../header}
\begin{document}
 …`
 
I got the error message "custom1.tex not found". What's wrong?

Comment: That's pretty confusing... Why don't you post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?