# How to split a sheet of exercises in different files, one file containing just one exercise?

Tags: exercises, multiple-files

I have a big file having the following structure :

```
\begin{exo}
...
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}
...
\end{exo}
```

My aim is to create different files containing just one exercice. How can I do this ? Does there exist a software ?

Comment: It should be easy enough to split out the exercises from LaTeX itself, defining `{exo}` in imitation of `{filecontents}`. But what about the file naming?

Comment: Finally I used a Python script to do this. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Two links which can help you. [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101479/1952) explains how to use LuaTeX to obtain different `.tex` files from the original one an [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224429/1952) explains how to use `tcolorbox` to extract contents from one file to other ones which can be later on included or just leaved for independet processing. The second solution could be applied redefining your `exo` enviroments.

Comment: @jowe_19 Can you post your python script as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs users can perform this function.

```
(defun save-environments (env)
  "Collects all the ENV environments (default to EXO) to save them each in a separate file. Replaces each with an \input"
  (interactive
   (list (read-string "Environment: " "exo")))
  (with-current-buffer (buffer-name)
    (let ((env-number 0)
          (file-se (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-name))))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      
      (while
          (search-forward  (format"\\begin{%s}" env) nil t)
        (setq env-number (1+ env-number))
        (LaTeX-mark-environment)
        (kill-region (point) (mark))
        (with-temp-file (format "%s-%s-%d.tex" file-se env  env-number)
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (insert (format "%% %s-%s-%d.tex\n" file-se env env-number)
                  (format "%% From %s.tex \n\n" file-se))
          
          (yank))
        (insert (format "\\input{%s-%s-%d}\n" file-se env env-number))))))
```

It can be used for any environment, default is exo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard latex functionality such as the import libraries and manually split up exercises into individual files. And then use either `import` with relatives paths via subimport, use just use the full path.

[How to use the import package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58465/how-to-use-the-import-package)

I think the main issue would be getting all the commands into separate files.

However if you wish to automatic this process, you may need to use a scripting language like python and do something similar to web scrapping using a tool like [TexSoup](https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup)

Comment: I think this is the contrary of what the OP asked. S/He has a unique file and wants to create many files.

Answer (score 0):

That is not really an answer but this can help you.

I have used the following pieces of code to manage a lot of questions written in different files.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\nbquest{16}

\newcommand\dirofquest{01-no-parabola}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,\nbquest}{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Question FLASH no. \n}
    
        \Large\centering
    
        \input{\dirofquest/question-\n.tex}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the contrary of what the OP asked. S/He has a unique file and wants to create many files.