# Large document multifile structure with pgf and data subfolders using import

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, import, multiple-files

My project file structure is:

```
C:\USERS\NAME\MULTIFILE_MWE
│   main.tex
│
├───pgf
│       data.csv
│       pgftikz_fig.tex
│
└───sections
        section_import.tex
```

My requirements are:

- `main.tex` file brings together many sections.
- Each section compiles independently and calls on pgf code stored in `./pgf/`.
- Each pgf file compiles independently and reads `.csv`.

I can compile `pgftikz_fig.tex` independently and I can compile `section_import.tex` independently. I cannot compile `main.tex`.

#### Data

`data.csv`

```
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
```

#### PGF plot file

```
% pgftikz_fig.tex
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {./pgf/data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Master file

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\import{sections/}{section_import}

\end{document}
```

#### Section file

```
% section_import.tex
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\subimport{./pgf/}{pgftikz_fig.tex}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution using \subimport

In the `main.tex` file I should use `\subimport` not `\import`

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\subimport{sections/}{section_import}

\end{document}
```

In the `section_import.tex` file I should use the correct file pointer `../` not `./`

```
% section_import.tex
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\subimport{../pgf/}{pgftikz_fig}

\end{document}
```

#### Solution using \input

`main.tex` will compile if `section_import.tex` uses `\input` rather than `\subimport`:

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\input{./pgf/pgftikz_fig.tex}

\end{document}
```

However I prefer to use the `import` package because my full project is more complex than the minimal example I have provided. In the full project I reference figures and I have citations within each section. `input` is less powerful for this than `import`.

Comment: I found this answer useful https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58485/46516. I do not know the difference between `\subimport` and `\subimport*`.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference now; the star versions are accepted so old documents can be processed.

Comment: Since the directory contents aren't hierarchical (nested), and there are no repeated file names,  it may be easier to specify `\makeatletter \input@path{{sections/}{pgf/}} \Ginput@path{{sections/}{pgf/}}`, and then use simple `\input{pgftikz_fig}` and `\input{section_import}`.