# Using a non-centralized structure for tex files - similar to \graphicspath

Tags: external-files, input

I have a fairly large document, that I have picked apart into different sections etc, each in their own file. To include graphics that are not in one central directory I use `\graphicspath` which works quite nicely. Is there a similar command I could use to include `tex` files from multiple directories without me explicitly naming them?

The idea would be the following:

```
\graphicspath{{./Some/Directory/For/Figures1/},{./Some/Directory/For/Figures2/}}
\texpath{{./Some/Directory/For/Tex/Files1/},{./Some/Directory/For/Tex/Files2/}}
```

The I would like to call within the document:

```
\includegraphics{fig_from_Figures1}% this works
\includegraphics{fig_from_Figures2}

\input{doc_from_Files1}% this would be awesome
\input{doc_from_Files2}
```

Comment: What TeX distribution and operating system are you using?

Comment: @egreg I am using TeX-Live 2013 on Linux

Comment: Maybe see also [include - How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files) (this is special case?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The facility used by the graphics package is in fact really for tex input files, it just locally redefines the path for graphics. Just define `\input@path` with the same syntax:

Graphics defines

```
\def\graphicspath#1{\def\Ginput@path{#1}}
```

and then locally within `\includegraphics` sets

```
  \let\input@path\Ginput@path
```

so if instead you just globally defined `\input@path`  it would affect `\input{}` and `\read`.

However for both TeX files and graphics I would probably not use this mechanism (even though I implemented it) but instead just set TEXINPUTS=.//: before running LaTeX and then all subdirectories of the current directory will be searched anyway.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you avoid these graphics and tex file path definitions?

Comment: @Markus, well mainly the kpathsea search algorithm is implemented in C and the latex input@path algorithm is implemented in TeX macros and is a gazillion times slower.