# How to copy figures and "input"ed LaTeX source files from absolute directories to a local one?

Tags: input

For example, in my `main.tex` I use

```
\input{/home/certain-directory/chapter-1.tex}
```

and

```
\input{/home/another-directory/chapter-2.tex}
```

I also have some figures included by their absolute paths in my `/home/results-directory`.

**Question:**

Are there any tools available for copying the source with figures to another directory (with sub-directories to hold the figures)?

Such that we can compile on another PC without manually editing the absolute paths.

Comment: related(?): [Using a non-centralized structure for tex files - similar to \graphicspath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128067)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks. But I had figures with the same name in different directories. And I named a directory like `parameterNameAndValue`.

Comment: This would be a very useful utility. But no answers here. Waiting.

Comment: Easy to do in `lualatex` without resorting to command line utilities.  If this question is still around in a couple of days then I'll write something up; busy now.

Comment: @JPi Looking forward to your solution!

Comment: The question is absolutely unclear. And as per your provided answer it is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to write a script to perform this.

As being lack of knowledge of command line tools like `xargs`, `find`, `grep`, and `sed`, 
I stopped at the following (just to extract the figure names)

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\\includegraphics\[.*\]{\(.*\)}/\1/p'  main.tex > temp_figures
 fig/laurana_view30_50.png
```

At present I would edit `temp_figures` in `Vim` to vertically add `cp` on each line, and complete the missing extensions of figure names using `c-x c-f`

And rather than copy all the files with the same directory structure (with `cp --parents`, sadly which is not directly avaialable on `Mac OSX`), I would probably use the new filenames like:

`sed -n 's/.*\\includegraphics\[.*\]{\(.*\)}/\1/p'  main.tex | sed 's/\//_/p'`

`fig_laurana_view30_50.png`

Hope this helps, and hopefully I would have time later to grab the necessary knowledge to find a better solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question since these commands are editing the absolute paths!