# Is there an equivalent to \graphicspath for listings?

Tags: listings, paths

How can I make the `\lstinputlisting` to search for files in a given directory? I'm thinking of a solution along the lines of the solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128067/using-a-non-centralized-structure-for-tex-files-similar-to-graphicspath/128076#128076).

I would like to have a solution like

```
\lstinputpath{/some/path/in/the/system}
\lstinputlisting{file.ext}
```

where `file.ext` resides in `/some/path/in/the/system`. I tried to search for such solution without luck. I found that inside of the definition of `\lstinputlistings` the authors use a `\lst@inputpath`. However, a naive modification of this macro doesn't yield any results.

Comment: related (sort of): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79058/can-a-default-path-be-set-globally-for-input-akin-to-graphicspath

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `listings` package provides a key called `inputpath` for specifying a path where `\lstinputlisting` should search for source files. Note that `inputpath` is only documented in the `listings` developer's guide, *not* in the user manual; if you haven't compiled the developer's guide, searching for "inputpath" in [listings.dtx](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx) will lead you to the definition of the `inputpath` key. To use the latter, simply write

```
\lstset{inputpath=<path-in-question>}
```

somewhere in your document (not necessarily in your preamble, but after loading `listings`, of course). If you really insist on using a macro similar to `\graphicspath`, you can define an `\lstinputpath` macro yourself, like so

```
\newcommand*\lstinputpath[1]{\lstset{inputpath=#1}}
```

The code below assumes that the file `sample.c` resides in a subdirectory called `test` of your working directory.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*\lstinputpath[1]{\lstset{inputpath=#1}}

\lstinputpath{test}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
  language   = C,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  frame      = single,
  caption    = {Hello world in C},
]{sample.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The use of the key is cleaner than redefining the macro. I didn't found that key when going through the code. Authors should really make that more clear.

Comment: @adn See my edit.

Comment: Is there any way to bring up the developer's guide via `texdoc`?

Comment: @SeanAllred I'm not sure, but I don't think so. The user's guide explains how to generate the developer's guide, though.

Comment: Are multiple paths allowed? If so, could you modify the answer to demonstrate multiple paths?

Comment: @kando As far as I know, no.

Comment: One important drawback that should be noted here is that the inputpath is *always* prepended even if the supplied argument contains slashes (and even if it starts with one i.e. if it is an absolute path).

Answer (score 2):

Alternative includes using `\input@path` LaTeX internal macro.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24827/250119, [Can a default path be set globally for \input{...} akin to \graphicspath{...}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79058/250119).

e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{SubFolder/}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
  language   = C,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,
  frame      = single,
  caption    = {Hello world in C},
]{SubTest.tex}
\end{document}
```

**Advantage**: It works, supports multiple paths, and does not suffer from the disadvantage mentioned in [the comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167640/is-there-an-equivalent-to-graphicspath-for-listings/167647#comment1118072_167647)

> One important drawback that should be noted here is that the inputpath is always prepended even if the supplied argument contains slashes (and even if it starts with one i.e. if it is an absolute path).

**Disadvantage**:

- As far as I can see `\input@path` is an internal macro of LaTeX, and its **original** purpose isn't even to allow users to extend the possible locations for `\input`...? (details later)
- This only works because `listings` package documentation **just happens to** internally use `\input` to process the file internally. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

[image: listings source code documentation]

<sub>(by the way using `\active` to represent the constant 13 for `\endlinechar` is the opposite of self-documented code.)</sub>

Comment: Link to some related questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21904/input-and-absolute-paths https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79058/can-a-default-path-be-set-globally-for-input-akin-to-graphicspath https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439906/inputpath-and-load-path-priority