# LyX - Error when including a file with a listing

Tags: errors, listings, lyx, input

I'm new to LyX/Latex and this is my first project in which I'm using it, so I don't know if I was specific enough in the title.

To write this project, I was given a template made of multiple files:

- `outline.lyx`;
- `solution.lyx`;
- `simulation.lyx`.

All these files are included (with `input`) in a main file, let's call it `main.lyx`.

In `solution.lyx` I used the ERT:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption={Component}]{design/component.blif}
```

to make a listing that "includes" directly the source of my code, instead of having to copy it manually. The directory "design" (in which there is *component.blif*) is in the same directory of `solution.lyx`.

Now comes the problem. If I put `main.lyx` in the same directory of `solution.lyx` and generate the PDF with pdflatex, everything seems to work fine. If I put `main.lyx` one step "higher" in the path (so that includes, for istance, "ex01/solution.lyx"), LyX gives me the following error:

> Package Listings Error: File `design/component(.blif)' not found.
>       *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? I would really like to put the main file one step higher, so that I can include multiple files from different sub-directories.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167640/15925 which would suggest putting `\lstset{inputpath=ex01}` in the main file.