# \input@path and load path priority?

Tags: packages, input, kpathsea

I have a project structure

```
.
├── includes
│   ├── apxproof.sty
│   └── somecustommodule.sty
└── tex
    └── document.tex
```

including a bugfix version of `apxproof.sty` and setting `\input@path` in `document.tex` to `\def\input@path{{../includes}}`.

Upon invoking `cd tex; pdflatex document`, while `somecustommodule.sty` is loaded as expected by `\usepackage`, for `apxproof` the globally installed package of MikTeX is used.

This made me wonder: What is the search order of the LaTeX paths with respect to `\input@path`, and can I make LaTeX prefer `../includes/` before the distribution files, without relying on system-wide settings like `TEXINPUTS`?

My workaround currently is to use `\usepackage{../includes/apxproof}`, which raises a warning

```
You have requested package `../includes/apxproof', but the package provides `apxproof'.
```

It is possible to use the *silece* package to filter out such warnings, but I'd rather not risk missing relevant warnings.

### The full mockup example

```
%% ==== tex/document.tex

\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{../includes/}}
\usepackage{apxproof}
\usepackage{somecustommodule}
\begin{document}
\SomeCustomCommand
\ApxproofCustomCommand
\end{document}

%% ==== includes/apxproof.sty

\newcommand{\ApxproofCustomCommand}{(from apxproof.sty)}

%% ==== includes/somecustommodule.sty

\newcommand{\SomeCustomCommand}{(from somecustommodule.sty)}
```

Comment: The same priority problem pops up with document files and`\graphicspath` as well such that some common file names must be considered reserved by the system: `list.tex`, `variations.tex`, `left.pdf`, `hand.png`. To include document files, `./file name` can be used instead of just `file name`. See https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `\input@path` processing is pretty simple it just prepends the supplied directories to the filename however for "efficiency" reasons it always tries the filename as given first so

```
\input{somecustommodule.sty}
```

will try in order

`\realinput{somecustommodule.sty}` then `\realinput{../includes/somecustommodule.sty}`

using a full `kpathsea` file search in each case.

Presumably here the first one fails and so the file is found by the second, as you wanted.

However with a standard package such as `apxproof.sty` the first one succeeds so the `\input@path` isn't used.

Personally I'd use TEXINPUTS (even though I implemented `\input@path` :-) it does not have to be a system-wide setting, you can (in most command shells) set it just for a single invocation if you wish, eg in bash you can do

```
 TEXINPUTS=../includes: pdflatex myfile
```

alternatively (and generally simpler) give the fixed version of `apxproof.sty` a different name so you do not rely on the directory path search order to distinguish the two files.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution: prepend the file names with `./`.

Once you want to switch back to the system style, remove the `./`.

### Working code

Assuming `../includes` conforms to the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{../includes}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{./apxproof}
\usepackage{./somecustommodule}
\begin{document}
\SomeCustomCommand
\ApxproofCustomCommand
\end{document}
```

### Explanation

If the file path being searched for is **absolute or explicitly relative**, i.e., starts with ‘/’ or ‘./’ or ‘../’, TeX via Kpathsea simply checks if that file exists, with a fallback to a casefolding match if needed and enabled.

### Rule of thumb

All document level file path should be **absolute or explicitly relative** for 2 reasons:

1. It speeds up the file looking mechanism
2. It prevents actual and future **name collisions**

If you do not use a leading `.` or `/`

1. next very common file names can't be used inside subfolders with `\input@path`, `\l_file_search_path_seq` and `\graphicspath` mechanisms: `list.tex`, `variations.tex`, `left.pdf`, `hand.png`...
2. A change in the TeX distribution can insidiously **break your document** behind your back, more importantly, it can break your document **silently**!

It is possible to safely use `middle.pdf` today,
but next year, this name
can be used by a package, like `left.pdf` and `right.pdf` already
are, silently taking precedence over your own included document.

Things get more complex with MikTeX base TeX distribution concept: loading a new package can break existing document.