# Add search path for \usetikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-pgf, input

How could I add a folder to the search path of tikz?

More precisely, I have a structure like this (see below for exact content):

```
mycachedfiles/a.tex
myinput.tex
tikzlibrarymy.test.code.tex
```

I’d like to compile it using:

```
cd mycachedfiles
pdflatex a.tex
```

However, if `myinput.tex` contains `\usetikzlibrary{my.test}`, then I will get an error like:

```
! Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'my.test'. I looked for f
iles named tikzlibrarymy.test.code.tex and pgflibrarymy.test.code.tex, but neit
her could be found in the current texmf trees..
```

I tried to play with `\subimport`, `\input@path`… without success. Any idea?

**MWE**

```
% a.tex:
\documentclass[]{article}
\makeatletter
% Works for \input{} but not for \usetikzlibrary
\def\input@path{{..}}
\makeatother

% Not working:
% \input{../myinput.tex}
% Not better:
\usepackage{import}%
\subimport{../}{myinput.tex}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[my test style]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

```
% myinput.tex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{my.test}
```

```
% tikzlibrarymy.test.code.tex:
\tikzset{
  my test style/.style={
    draw,
    circle,
    fill=red,
  }
}
```

Comment: A few complicated things in play here. `\input@path` affects `\input` but not `\@@input`, try `TEXINPUTS`. (that having said I believe there hasn't been something that explains what's the difference between the 2 above and e.g. `\l_file_search_path_seq`, `graphicpath` etc.)

Comment: @user202729 thanks, but can’t I find a generic solution working without touching environment variables? (they are not easy to change in my setting)

Comment: Probably need to patch TikZ code then.

Comment: Maybe you can work around the problem by placing a symlink to tikzlibrarymy.test.code.tex in your cached folder?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yeah, I guess it’s a solution, but I don’t find it very elegant. For instance I can’t copy the code on a usb stick as fat16 does not handle symlinks…

Comment: I'd say almost everything is more elegant than patching TikZ code. For FAT16 you can replace the symlink idea with a file with content of a single line `\input{correct/path/to/file}`

Comment: This trick is nice. I would not want to patch TikZ myself, true. But I’d love to see TikZ patch its own code ^^ I submitted an issue in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One brute workaround: insert

```tex
\makeatletter
\let\pgfutil@IfFileExists     =\IfFileExists
\let\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists=\InputIfFileExists
\makeatother
```

just before

```tex
\usetikzlibrary{my.test}
```

in `myinput.tex`.

Or if its OK to make `tikzlibrarymy.test.code.tex` seen by all your local LaTeX runs, you can create symlink(s) for path to `tikzlibrarymy.test.code.tex` (or the directory it lives in) in proper subdirectory of TDS tree `TEXMFHOME` or `TEXMFLOCAL`, for example

```bash
$(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries
# or just
$(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/generic/pgf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it seems like if I do so, if there exists a library with the same name installed system-wide, then the one specified in `\input@path` will not have priority (unledd I missed something)… is it possible to say that the `\input@path` should have priority?

Comment: Thought possible, I don't think that's the right way to go.  Current behavior is the one `\IfFileExists` and `\InputIfFileExists` from LaTeX use, for example the system-wide `tikz.sty` has priority than any modified `tikz.sty` in any of the paths in `\input@path`.  I suggest to use another library name. You can load the system-wide "version" with `\usetikzlibraray` and then put your own modifications in your library source file.

Comment: Oh, is it possible? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439906/inputpath-and-load-path-priority suggests that it’s not (unless playing with environment variables… heck) Also, having a separate name is not extremely practical as the library (for this second usecase) is in a submodule, and it would be a nightmare to synchronize them. Guess I will use for this usecase `\input` even if it’s not extremely clean.

Comment: By providing a modified pair of `\pgfutil@IfFileExists` and `\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists` with path priority modified, I guess it's possible.

Comment: Oh I see, make sense, thanks.