# Relative paths to tex files?

Tags: input, include, paths, texinputs

In the preamble of my tex document I can set `graphicspath`. Is it also possible to set a path to sub sections and tables, so I can do `\input{relative-path/filename.tex}` from any tex file and move that text file to any location?

I am not trying to import a package.

I want to be able to go from this directory structure:

```
images/image1.png
figures/figure1.tex
tables/table1.tex
section1/filename.tex
main.tex
```

To this directory structure (i.e. change the location of `filename.tex` to a sub directory or move it to the root directory):

```
chapter1/images/image1.png
chapter1/figures/figure1.tex
chapter1/tables/table1.tex
chapter1/section1/filename.tex
chapter1/main.tex
```

It will break, if main.tex contains `\input{chapter1/filename.tex}`. Can I avoid manually having to change that to `\input{chapter1/section1/filename.tex}` upon changing the directory structure?

Comment: you can do `\input{relative-path/filename.txt}` anyway without any preamble setup?

Comment: As far as I know, you can. Did you try it?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath It seems as if graphicspath is intended for absolute paths? For relative paths, you can do something like `\graphicspath{{subdir1/}{subdir2/}{subdir3/}...{subdirn/}}`

Comment: the analogue of graphicspath for input would allow you to use `\input{filename}` having specified the path in the preamble, Actually latex has that facility for `\input` and `\includegraphics` just locally uses it,  there is an existing answer somewhere I'll find it...

Comment: Yes, but what happens, when I move the file to a subdirectory? Then it breaks.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen why does it break?

Comment: for both tex and images it is much better not to ue `\graphicspath` (`\input@path`) but simply use `\input{file}` or `\includegraphics{file}` and make sure that the file is in a directory in your TEXINPUTS then it works from anywhere just as `\documentclass{article}` always finds `article.cls`

Comment: @Wamseln I don't understand your comment about absolute paths.

Comment: @David Carlisle - Suppose you have the main .tex-file in a certain folder. And also in that folder you have several subdirectories, in which you have all the graphic files. You can then specify these subdirectories with  `\graphicspath{{subdir1/}{subdir2/}{subdir3/}}` and all you have to do then is to use `\includegraphics{graphic1.png}` or `\includegraphics{graphic2.png}`.  These files will be found no matter in which of the specified subdirectories the included graphics are, hence you are able to move them around, but: they have to be in one of the specified directories.

Comment: @Wamseln Exactly! But can this also be done for tex files?

Comment: Ok, got your question wrong! Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128067/using-a-non-centralized-structure-for-tex-files-similar-to-graphicspath

Comment: @Wamseln I know how `\graphicspath` works (I wrote that command) but it doesn't have anything to do with "absolute paths". but anyway as i say above the underlying mechanism is implemented for `\input`,  `\includegraphics`  just locally redefines the path to use a different path for image files.

Comment: @Wamseln ah well found, I was looking for that, I knew it was somewhere:-) so probably this question is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - sorry for that. (And thank you!) I guess, what I wrote is just nonsense then. What I meant to say was, for specifying subdirectories `\includegraphics` might be sufficient. But since one can also use absolute paths in `\graphicspath`, it might come in very handy if you want to do something like: `\graphicspath{{/absolute/path/to/directory1/}{/absolute/path/to/a/completely/different/directory2/}{/absolute/path/to/yet/another/completely/different/directory3/}}`. But of course, I must confess being guilty of not having understood the matter sufficiently before commenting.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Using a non-centralized structure for tex files - similar to \graphicspath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128067/using-a-non-centralized-structure-for-tex-files-similar-to-graphicspath)

Comment: @Wamseln Thanks! I will try that thing `TEXINPUTS=.//:`. Not sure where to add it. I will try it before I begin the document. Maybe I should have stuck to Word+Endnote after all :) Oh dear...