Save specific parent folder name to variable?
I'm trying to obtain the parent folder name since the parent folder name changes but the subfolder's structure is the same.
For example, I have scripts in the directories:
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\<ProjectName1>\Main\MainScript.tex
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\<ProjectName2>\Main\MainScript.tex
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\<ProjectName3>\Main\MainScript.tex
In MainScript.tex, can I save the parent folder name <ProjectNameX> as a variable without using multiple "../"?
The reason why I'm avoiding "../" is the file path being too long in Windows for my actual projects. I'm using environment variables instead but adding environment variables for each project is not feasible.

Hello! Does this maybe help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25572/172164

why do you need the parent directories listed in the tex file? It seems quite an unusual requirement?

@DavidCarlisle My workaround on the parent folder name is to use a series of "../" from the main script, but adding multiple "../" into the renders it too long for windows (260 characters), hence why I'm using system environment variables to eliminate the "../" and long paths. However, the parent directories have different names, which I'm hoping to use the parent folder name as a variable and automate my main script templates.

it would be easier to understand your question if you showed some example. it is very unusual to need the absolute path in a tex file or to worry about its length, most tex documents can be moved into any folder and just work in place, you can obviously save the folder name with eg \newcommand\parentfolder{ProjectName3} but without knowing how you intend to use this it's hard to really say if that is an answer.
