# Path of includegraphics is relative - but to what?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am trying to include graphics for a document.  The arborescence is as follows:

```
+ REPORT
+-- RESOURCES
|   + icon.png
+-- TEX
    + report.tex
    + report.cls
```

The report.tex starts with `{report}`, and the `report.cls` file has the following lines :

```
\RequirePackage(graphicx)
[...]
\includegraphics[...]{../RESOURCES/icon}
```

Now, when I run `pdflatex` on that `.tex` like this, everything runs smoothly :

```
> pdflatex report.tex
```

However, when I run it from another directory, it *seems* to me that the "relative" path is taken as "relative from the execution directory" and not "relative from the .tex file".

```
> pdflatex TEX/report.tex
[...]
!pdfTex error : pdflatex file {../RESOURCES/icon.png} : cannot find image file
```

This seems to be confirmed by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95618/95394) answer.

I tried using `\graphicspath{{../RESOURCES/}}` before my `\begin{document}`, but it wasn't successful.

So, my question is : is there any way of having relative paths in `.tex` regarded as relative *to the `.tex`* rather than *to the execution dir* when using `pdflatex`?

Comment: no, basically:-)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65178/relative-paths-dont-work-without-absolute-path

Comment: unrelated but I would seriously consider not calling your local class file `report.cls` as that clashes with the standard latex `report` class.

Answer (score 4):

It is a feature of the underlying tex system that relative paths are relative to the working directory not to the directory of the current file or the top level file of the document. This applies to input tex files and packages as well as images.