# Latex command /input relative adressing problem

Tags: input

My Latex project is organized like this:

In my root Latex folder there is a root latex file named **main.tex**. 
In the same folder there is a subfolder *pictures* which contains 2 files named **test.tex** and **test.pdf**.

Problem occurs when in first file **main.tex** i input second file **test.tex** using `\input{./pictures/test.tex}`.

But in second file **test.tex** there is a line which includes a third file **test.pdf**. This is done using `\includegraphics{test.pdf}` *(I cant change this as it is an output from a third party software)*

Because **test.tex** gets inputed in **main.tex**, **test.tex** cannot find **test.pdf** with a `\includegraphics{test.pdf}`. It could find it if i could modify this line into `\includegraphics{./pictures/test.pdf}`, but i can not do this.

What are my options if i can only modify **main.tex**?

Comment: Alternative option →[include - How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files)I believe that should work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
\graphicspath{{pictures/}}
```

to your document preamble. This will add `pictures/` to the search path for graphics if the image included is not found in the root folder. See [Importing graphics from “somewhere else”](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-graphicspath) on the TeX FAQ.