# Set a subfolder for \include(only)

Tags: include, filesystem-access

Let’s assume a project with a main file `main.tex` including the chapter with `\include`.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{book}

\includeonly{one}

\begin{document}
\include{one}
\include{two}
\end{document}
```

```
% one.tex
\chapter{First chapter}
Some text
```

```
% two.tex
\chapter{Second chapter}
Some text
```

To keep the diretory clean the chapters should be saved in a folder named `chapters/`. Doing this means also to add the folder to each `\include` macro and to `\includeonly` too.

```
\documentclass{book}

\includeonly{chapters/one}

\begin{document}
\include{chapters/one}
\include{chapters/two}
\end{document}
```

So I wonder if it is possible to change the default path used with `\include(only)`?

Comment: The answers in [How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4602/5764) provide solutions to your problem. For example, the suggested [`inputx`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44215/5764) and [`import`](http://ctan.org/pkg/import) packages.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you! But as far as I can see `import` doesn’t provide what I need … `inputx` isn’t on CTAN, is it?

Comment: No, [`inputx`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44215/5764) is provided as part of the answer. Since I haven't tried it, this would be an optimal opportunity to test it out and push an answer-to-package...

Comment: @Werner: Are you blackstev? Would you like to make a official package out of it and send it to CTAN?

Comment: No. I've asked a question about this on Meta - [Repackaging code of absent user(s)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2856/5764)

Comment: @Werner: OK, thanks, let’s see what happens :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be possible to hack the definition of `\include(only)`. It seems to work but I’m not sure about the consequences …

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\include#1{\relax
   \ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux
     \@latex@error{\string\include\space cannot be nested}\@eha
   \else \@include{chapters/#1} \fi%
}
\def\includeonly#1{%
   \@partswtrue
   \edef\@partlist{\zap@space chapters/#1 \@empty}%
}
\makeatother

\includeonly{one}

\begin{document}
\include{one}
\include{two}
\end{document}
```

I thought about make this a little package providing a macro `\includepath{<dir>}` to add the directory automatically. Would this work without any harms?

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@includepath{}
\newcommand*{\includepath}[1]{%
   \xdef\@includepath{#1}%
}
\@onlypreamble\includepath
\def\include#1{\relax
   \ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux
     \@latex@error{\string\include\space cannot be nested}\@eha
   \else \expandafter\@include{\@includepath#1} \fi%
}
\def\includeonly#1{%
   \@partswtrue
   \edef\@partlist{\expandafter\zap@space\@includepath#1 \@empty}%
   \renewcommand*{\includepath}[1]{%
      \typeout{ERROR: \string\includepath\space must be
      used before \string\includeonly!}
   }
}
\makeatother


\includeonly{two}

\begin{document}
\include{one}
\include{two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If some file to `\include` is not in the `chapters` subfolder you have a problem.

Comment: @egreg: I tested it an the only problem is `No file chapters/one.tex` which is the same with the original `\include` when a file is missing, isn’t it?

Comment: I was thinking to the fact that you can't use `\includeonly` for referring to a file that doesn't live in `chapters`.

Comment: @egreg: OK thanks, but there aren’t other problems?