# Path problem with included file inside of a standalone file

Tags: standalone

How can I get the current path inside an included standalone file?

**1. Theoretical Example:**

let's assume the following directory structure:

```
main.tex
img/
 |-standalonefile.tex
 |-data
```

**standalonefile.tex**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \somecommand{data}
\end{document}
```

**main.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \includestandalone{img/standalonefile}
\end{document}
```

Now `standalonefile.tex` compiles, but `main.tex` can't find `data`. 
I couldn't find a way to use path from `\includestandalone` somehow inside `standalonefile.tex`.

**2. Practical example with `pgfplots` (MWE)** (I'm looking for a general solution)

directory structure:

```
main.tex
plots/
 |- plot1/
     |- plot1.tex
     |- data.csv
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \includestandalone{plots/plot1/plot1}
\end{document}
```

**plot1.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=semicolon]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**data.csv**

```
x;y
0;0
1;1
```

Now `plot1.tex` compiles fine,  but with `main.tex` the `data.csv` can't be found.

**Ideas for a solution**

- a command like `\mystandalonedir` that would return

  - the relative path to the main file, if included with `\includestandalone`
  - nothing, if not included
- change the base dir somehow with the `\includestandalone`
- (or something else ;) )

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files

Comment: Oh, I see closing votes ;)  If I read the suggested page correctly the solutions over there are only for `\input` an `\include` commands. But I'll take another look at it.

Comment: **I don't think it's a duplicate.** A solution to your problem would involve some patching of `\includestandalone`. If your question gets closed, I'll vote to reopen it. Martin Scharrer is the author of the `standalone` package and a moderator on the site. If he sees your question, I'm sure he'll come up with some solution.

Comment: With `docmute`+`import` packages in the main file you can use `\subimport{img/}{standalonefile}`. Note that in this case the preamble of the nested file is lost (among another problems like references) but you can `\input` a common preamble in both files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just combined Thomas F. Sturm answer with automatic string splitting. This way `\includestandalonewithpath` can be used the same way as `\includestandalone`.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\includestandalonewithpath}[2][]{%
    \begingroup%
    \StrCount{#2}{/}[\matches]%
    \StrBefore[\matches]{#2}{/}[\datapath]%
    \includestandalone[#1]{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
    \includestandalonewithpath{plots/plot1/plot1}
\end{document}
```

**plot1.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\providecommand{\datapath}{.}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=semicolon]{\datapath/data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution sadly does not seem to work for me. The \datapath macro seemingly is not transferred to the standalone.
Has anything changed in the past ten 10 years?

Answer (score 13):

My answer is possibly not a very elegant one, but it's roughly the way I handle this problem with my own files. The basic idea is to set up a path macro `\datapath`.

For your given **practical example**, I suggest the following:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\newcommand{\includestandalonewithpath}[3][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \newcommand{\datapath}{#2}%
  \includestandalone[#1]{\datapath/#3}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}
  \includestandalonewithpath{plots/plot1}{plot1}
\end{document}
```

**plot1.tex**

```
\providecommand{\datapath}{.}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=semicolon]{\datapath/data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution will also work, if your data file is in a subdirectory relative to **plot1.tex**, e.g.

```
plots/plot1/data/data.csv
```

Then, you would have:

```
\addplot table [x=x, y=y, col sep=semicolon]{\datapath/data/data.csv};
```

Comment: thank you! I just awarded the bounty to you and extended your solution with some string splitting.