# Standalone in build mode forget command

Tags: pgfplots, standalone, directory

I would like to know if it is possible to give a command that `includestandalone` would remember when building the pdf.

To explain a bit more, I like to put all my extra data like my `standalone` subfiles in a subfolder. I would like to do a plot with `pgfplots` from a CSV file itself in a subsubfolder (from the main). Therefore the structure is the following:

```
main.tex
Supplies/
   |-standaloneplot.tex
   |-Data/
      |-file.csv
```

And the files are the `file.csv`:

```
# Coord_X, Coord_Y
 0.0 , 1.0
 1.0 , 2.0
```

the `standaloneplot.tex`:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\providecommand{\PathS}{./}

\usepackage{tikz}                       % 
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   %
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}         %

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}     
    \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Space },    % 
            ylabel={\PathS }
            ]           

        \addplot[ color=blue,   ]
            table[x=Coord_X, y=Coord_Y, ignore chars={\#}, col sep=comma] 
            {\PathS \detokenize{Data/file}.csv};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand{\PathS}{./Supplies/}

\usepackage{standalone}             %
\usepackage{tikz}                   %
\usepackage{pgfplots}               %
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}         %

\begin{document}
 the path is \PathS
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone[mode=build, width=0.5\linewidth]{\PathS standaloneplot.tex}
        \caption{test}
        \label{lab}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I deal with this structure by defining a command in the main and in the `standalone` file. And it works correctly when I include the standalone file in a `tex` mode. This is, I think, close to the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147899/path-problem-with-included-file-inside-of-a-standalone-file). But when I use the build mode it forgets this command, which seems natural from my understanding of this mode.

Thus, I would like to know if it possible to work-around this problem and keep this structure and the use of `standalone` in `build` mode and `pgfplots`.
Maybe there is a way not to forget a command before to build the standalone file or a way for standalone to act more like the tex mode.

Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `mode=build`, the standalone file is compiled separately. Therefore, commands defined in the main file are unknown in the standalone file. But commands can be defined before a TeX file by calling the compiler like this:

```
pdflatex <some options> '\newcommand{\SomeMacro}{content}\input{texfile}'
```

Then `\SomeMacro` is defined in `texfile.tex`.

`standalone` offers the option `build` to setup the build command (see section 5.4 and table 3 of the manual). Here `command` sets the whole command (by default: `build={command=\latex\space\latexoptions\space\file}`). The last part (`\file`, containing the file name given to `\includestandalone`) has to be changed to define the macro before compiling the file. The necessary quotes are provided by `\quote`, so this is independent from the used OS. And some commands must be protected against expansion with `\string`. So by writing

```
build={command={\latex\space\latexoptions\space\quote\string\newcommand{\string\PathS}{\PathS}\string\input{\file}\quote}}
```

you can achieve your goal. In principle, you can define many commands this way by repeating `\string\newcommand{\string...}{...}` as often as needed. Note that you have to protect the command to be defined, but on the other hand, you can use `\PathS` instead of repeating the path.

The `build` option can be used with `includestandalone` or with `\standaloneconfig{...}` either somewhere in the document or in the preamble.

Remark: in the log file of `main.tex` near the end there is a line starting with `runsystem(` containing the command used to build the plot. This is useful to check, if the `build` option is set correctly.

Here is the new main.tex (other files are unchanged):

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand{\PathS}{./Supplies/}

\usepackage{standalone}             %
\usepackage{tikz}                   %
\usepackage{pgfplots}               %
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}         %

% set option build in the preamble, good for global path
\standaloneconfig{build={command={\latex\space\latexoptions\space\quote\string\newcommand{\string\PathS}{\PathS}\string\input{\file}\quote}}}

\begin{document}
% set option build somewhere in the document, good if path changes every couple of figures
%\standaloneconfig{build={command={\latex\space\latexoptions\space\quote\string\newcommand{\string\PathS}{\PathS}\string\input{\file}\quote}}}
 the path is \PathS
    \begin{figure}
        % use option build directly, good for individual paths
        %\includestandalone[build={command={\latex\space\latexoptions\space\quote\string\newcommand{\string\PathS}{\PathS}\string\input{\file}\quote}},mode=build, width=0.5\linewidth]{\PathS standaloneplot}
        \includestandalone[mode=build, width=0.5\linewidth]{\PathS standaloneplot}
        \caption{test}
        \label{lab}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```