# Standalone build command does not capture all length

Tags: standalone, lengths

I am working with `standalone` sub-file in `build` `mode`. I would like to pass lengths from the main file to the sub-file. To do so, according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439574/standalone-in-build-mode-forget-command) , I put it in the `command` used by `standalone` to create the PDF file.

But I am surprised by the different behaviour of some lengths in this command.

To illustrate my problem, here is a MWE:
`subfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}

    textheight:\the\textheight textwidth:\the\textwidth \ line:\the\linewidth and the baseline: \the\baselineskip \\
 An other line.

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

the `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}             %
    \standaloneconfig{build={command={\latex\space\latexoptions\space\quote\commandStandaloneBuild\string\input{\file}\quote} }
        }

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\commandStandaloneBuild}{%
        \string\AtBeginDocument\string{
            \string\setlength\string{\string\textwidth\string}\string{\the\textwidth\string}
            \string\setlength\string{\string\textheight\string}\string{\the\textheight\string}
            \string\setlength\string{\string\linewidth\string}\string{\the\linewidth\string}
            \string\setlength\string{\string\baselineskip\string}\string{\the\baselineskip\string}
        \string}
    }   
    \makeatother


\begin{document}

    \setlength{\baselineskip}{30pt} 
baseline: \the\baselineskip
\setlength{\linewidth}{200pt} 
the line :\the\linewidth
\setlength{\textwidth}{450pt}
the textwidth :\the\textwidth
\setlength{\textheight}{500pt}
the textheight :\the\textheight


    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includestandalone[mode=build,
            ]{subfile}
        \caption{test}
        \label{lab}
    \end{figure}

now the command is :\commandStandaloneBuild
\end{document}
```

In this case, results from the standalone built is a `linewidth` of `345pt` and a `baseline` of `12pt`, while it should be respectively `200pt` and `30pt`. But the `textwidth` and `textheight` are correct.
Thus, I checked the `main.log` and I found:

```
runsystem(pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -shell-escape -jobname 'subfile' '\AtBeginDocument{ \setlength{\textwidth}{450.0pt} \setlength{\textheight}{500.0pt}\setlength{\linewidth}{345.0pt}\setlength{\baselineskip}{12.0pt} } \input{subfile}')...executed.
```

Therefore, the information given by the subfile are those given by the build command, but the command 'printed' in the main is not the one passed to the build of standalone.

So, in order to solve my problem I have two related questions: How to make the build command behave the same way for all the `length`? And why this differences ?

Comment: if you set `\linewidth` at begin document to anything other than the value it has (which is \textwidth for single column documents, latex is going to get very confused. What is your intention of setting this (which is never intended to be set by hand in this way)? similarly `\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}` seems an odd construct as the table will be `\linewidth+2\tabcolsep` wide, and it is indendent by `\parindent` so will not fit on the line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I completely agree about the fact that my `tabular` will not fit the line, the purpose is not here. It was just to see the possible change of the `\baselineskip` length, because without `tabular` there is no line-break in the `standalone` class. Moreover, I do it this way because the class options `preview`, `varwidth` or `multi` will affect some lengths. And my intention is to test the limit of the method, with these unusual situations and settings.

Comment: `\baselineskip`, `\linewidth` etc are set at begin document based on other settings in the preamble setting \linewidth is never the right thing to do, I would suggest an alternative but I can not guess the intention here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, This is just a way to highlight my problem, not a final purpose. Even if, I put these settings in the preamble or even remove it, the evoked problem remains.

Comment: sorry but `\linewidth` is an internal latex parameter that _latex_ sets all over the place and keeps \textwidth, \linewidth, \@totaleftmargin\ and \hsize in correct relationship. I cannot work out the intention here other than you set \linewidth in one place and it has a different value somewhere else, but the solution for that is always not to set \linewidth. Sorry if this sounds unhelpful but I really can't guess the intention but setting \linewidth can never do anything useful and the fact that latex resets it to a different value is expected.

Comment: You can't pass baselineskip like this either. It is reset at every font size change.

Comment: I think I understand my mistake about `\linewidth` and `\baselineskip`. They are linked parameters (correct me if I am wrong). So what would be the proper way to change theses values then to ask to latex to recompute the relationships with the others parameters, in order to have the same values in the main.tex and in the command to buid the standalone file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Carlisle and  Ulrike Fischer mentioned, the variables `\linewidth` and `\baselineskip` are internal latex parameters. So they have to be set before the beginning of the document when latex compute them.

Thus, a easy work-around is to create local temporary length in the preambule.

```
% Define two new length to store the local values of linewidth and baselineskip.
\newlength{\locallinewidth}
\newlength{\localbaselineskip}
```

To update, these values a newcommand is needed.

```
% Update the local values.
\newcommand{\UpdateLineAndBaseLength}{
    \setlength{\localbaselineskip}{\the\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\locallinewidth}{\the\linewidth}
}
```

Therefore, we can change the `\commandStandaloneBuild` to incorporate the new variable.

```
\string\setlength\string{\string\linewidth\string}\string{\the\locallinewidth\string}
\string\setlength\string{\string\baselineskip\string}\string{\the\localbaselineskip\string}
```

Then a call of the new command before the `\begin{figure}` solves the problem.

```
\UpdateLineAndBaseLength{}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includestandalone[mode=build,
        ]{subfile}
    \caption{test}
    \label{lab}
\end{figure}
```