# How can I use relative paths?

Tags: input, include, paths, import, sharelatex

I want to add a table from a separate tex file to my document. I get an error saying the file vr_sets.tex is not found, when I do this in Chapter2/chapter2.tex:

```
\input{tab/vr_sets}
```

This also fails:

```
\input{./tab/vr_sets}
```

This works:

```
\input{Chapter2/tab/vr_sets}
```

But how can I avoid having to specify the full path each time I want to include content (e.g. tables, sections, figures) from another tex file in a sub directory of the "current working directory"? Is there no such thing as relative paths in tex?

In my main.text I have:

```
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
```

Comment: relative paths works, but they are relative to the directory you started (pdf)tex. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=docotherdir

Comment: Related question [include - How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem. I changed this:

```
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
```

To this:

```
\usepackage{import}
\import{Chapter2/}{chapter2.tex}
```

And I was then able to do inputs with relative paths.

Comment: This seems to break references, so not a viable solution.