# Include figure relative to path of package

Tags: packages, include

For my thesis I'm using a given package from my university (`titlepage.sty`). Inside this package a figure is included `VUB_logo`. However, I wanted to put the packages I use in a folder named `packages` and then include them. This makes my root directory less polluted with files.

So what I did was create a directory structure as such:

```
master-thesis
├── bibli.bib
├── images
├── _introduction.tex
├── listings
│   ├── ...
├── packages
│   ├── VUB_logo.pdf
│   ├── VUB_schild.pdf
│   ├── vubtitlepage.sty
│   └── mathpartir.sty
├── _prescience.tex
├── _relatedwork.tex
├── _ruleshorthands.sty
├── _semantic.tex
├── thesis.bbl
├── thesis.tex
└── todo.md
```

In `thesis.tex` I included my titlepage package as such `\usepackage{packages/vubtitlepage}`.

Inside the `vubtitlepage.sty` there is an include:

```
\includegraphics[width=75.5mm,height=15.25mm]{VUB_logo}
```

As I understand it the path is relative to the root directory (i.e., the path of `thesis.tex`). Consequently it tries to load the image from there.  It would be a solution to change the path of `VUB_logo` to `packages/VUB_logo` but that would couple my packages folder to parent directory. I was hoping to resolve this.

So far I also tried using `subimport` as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files), but it doesn't seem to work. Or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\usepackage{packages/vubtitlepage}` is incorrect, the argument to `\usepackage` should be a *name* not a file path (if the package had a `\ProvidesPackage` line you would get a warning about this).

Just use `\usepackage{vubtitlepage}` and arrange that the `packages` directory is in your TEXINPUTS path, then the package and its related images will be found.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but wouldnt this require anyone who wants to compile this document to modify their environment? I would like a solution keeps the  document autonomous (for lack of a better term).

Comment: not necessarily their OS environment, and not necessarily globally, you could set it in a `texmf.cnf` file or you could use `TEXINPUTS=.//: pdflatex thesis` as your commandline or you could not set TEXINPUTS at all and put the vubtitlepage in an existing tex input directory such as `~/texmf/tex/latex/vub`

Comment: Aha! This is excellent. I just used the alternative command for compilation. Since the document uses a makefile putting `TEXINPUTS=.//:` in front of the command was the easiest and most portable solution. Thank you very much!