# superscripts and footnotemarks break in nested \import with realscripts

Tags: luatex, fontspec, import

I managed to produce strange interference between nested `\import` and superscripts, made accessible for `LuaTeX` by `realscripts.sty`.

My document organisation depends on the comfortable, path-agnostic behaviour of `\import` (or something equivalent).
Once ago, when I started nesting `\import`s, I wondered if this would break some day.
It has worked remarkably well most of the time---except for an extreme case I stumbled on now:

The package [`realscripts`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/realscripts) makes the superscript alphabets of well-equipped OpenType fonts available as default `\textsuperscript` and footnote marks, as a drop-in for use alongside `fontspec`.
This normally works well, and it looks very nice to have some kind of optical sizes for single-size OTF fonts, as the font I use (Junicode) has.

Now this is no problem within the main document itself, and it also works when I include another document with footnotes via `\import`. BUT when this document contains another `\import` itself (second nesting level), footnote marks are prepended (both in the main and the footnote text) with a lot of file path/font name babble, which reads like kind of `fontspec` searching for the fonts in the directory of the second nesting.

MWE
(TeX Live 2015, `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (Web2C 2015) (rev 5238)` on both Linux and FreeBSD):

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\begin{document}
\subimport{}{importdirect.ltx} % This works

\subimport{}{importindirect.ltx} % This looks very strange
\end{document}
```

### importindirect.ltx

```
\subimport{}{importdirect.ltx}
```

### importdirect.ltx

```
Minimal broken example\footnote{footnote}
and \textsuperscript{textsuperscript}
```

Then run `lualatex main` (You can imagine how things break when I have underscores and such nasty things in my real paths and filenames).
Note that the superscripts themselves are typeset correctly!

This is font-dependent.
It happens to {Junicode} and {Linux Libertine O}, and possibly others.
TeX Gyre fonts seem to be immune.
It seems unrelated to [lualatex does not work with import/subimport when used in standalone setup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267572/96444) (at least, the first nesting level works without problems, and changing `\pdftexversion` didn't do the trick).

XeLaTeX deals with this case without any problem.

*My question, variant 1:* This seems to be a bug, either in `fontspec`'s LuaTeX interna, or in LuaTeX itself. What to do? (If it were of `realscripts`'s fault, XeTeX would break, too, wouldn't it?)

*My question, variant 2:* Is there a way to redefine superscript text (or footnote marks) so that they do not eat up the details of`fontspec` dealing with font selection?

*My question, variant 3:* Things break with nested `\import`s. What is wrong with `import.sty` (for TeXnical curiosity, or a fix), and/or (as a workaround) are there alternative import logics for external documents?

*My question, variant 4:* Things break with `realscripts`. Is there a (more) canonical way to load OpenType superscript styles, e. g. with `fontspec` itself? Why is LuaTeX affected and XeTeX not?

**[EDIT]** The result, produced with a fresh TeX Live 2015 install:

[image: The resulting main.pdf (compressed) with buggy footnote references]

Comment: I've tried to replicate this on my system (TL2015, mostly updated), and with a prerelease version of fontspec, and I don't see the same problems…

Comment: Hrm. With current TL16pretest (luatex-0.95.0, fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a), the issue still persists.